# Count number of rows in a many-to-many relationship (SQLAlchemy)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a many-to-many relationship between say blog entries and tags. Now I want to know how many entries a specific tag has.

Imagine the following models (simplified):

```
rel_entries_tags = Table('rel_entries_tags', Base.metadata,
  Column('entry_id', Integer, ForeignKey('entries.id')),
  Column('tag_id', Integer, ForeignKey('tags.id'))
)

class Entry(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'entries'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  title = Column(String(80))
  text = Column(Text)

  tags = relationship('Tag', secondary=rel_entries_tags, backref=backref('entries'))

  def __init__(self, title, text):
    self.title = title
    self.text = text
    self.tags = tags    

class Tag(Base):
  __tablename__ = 'tags'

  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  name = Column(String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)

  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
```

My approach to count the amount of entries for a tag is `len(db_session.query(Tag).get(1).entries)`. The problem is that when it gets `db_session.query(Tag).get(1).entries` SQLAlchemy selects all the entries with all their columns for a tag, however, I want only the amount of the entries, not the entries themselves. Is there a more optimal approach for this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
session.query(Entry).join(Entry.tags).filter(Tag.id==1).count()
```

or if you have a Tag already

```
session.query(Entry).with_parent(mytag, "entries").count()
```

Comment: +1: and if you need this often, you can create a property: `@property\n
def entries_cnt(self): \n    return Session.object_session(self).query(Entry).with_parent(self, "entries").count()
`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However, the produced SQL statement is `SELECT count(*) AS count_1 FROM (SELECT order_line.id AS order_line_id, order_line.order_id AS order_line_order_id FROM order_line 
WHERE %(param_1)s = order_line.order_id) AS anon_1`
In other words - instead of one `SELECT count(*) FROM order_line WHERE order_line.order_id = %(param_1)s` we get an inner SELECT. 
In my case, it's not one-to-many (Order has many OrderLine).

Comment: do a query(func.count('*')) up front.  the [count() documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html?highlight=query.count#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.count) refers to this.

Comment: It should also be OK to use `session.query(Entry).with_parent(mytag).count()`. [The `property` parameter can be omitted](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_parent.params.property)