# Counting relationships in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

My SQLAlchemy structure looks like this

```
papers2authors_table = Table('papers2authors', Base.metadata,
    Column('paper_id', Integer, ForeignKey('papers.id')),
    Column('author_id', Integer, ForeignKey('authors.id'))
)

class Paper(Base):
    __tablename__ = "papers"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    handle = Column(String)

    authors = relationship("Author",
                    secondary="papers2authors",
                    backref="papers")

class Author(Base):
    __tablename__ = "authors"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, unique=True)
    code = Column(String, unique=True)
```

I would like to query two things:

1. The numbers of authors in each paper
2. The numbers of papers each author has (partly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567666/count-number-of-rows-in-a-many-to-many-relationship-sqlalchemy))

I tried many options with `func.count()` and `count()`, but they return nonsensical results. How to do these two things in an SQLAlchemy way?

**What I tried**

- `db.s.query(func.count(core.Paper.id)).group_by(core.Author.id).first()` = `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such column: authors.id`
- `db.s.query(func.count(core.Author.papers)).group_by(core.Author.id).first()` = `(128100)`, which doesn't what I expected
- `db.s.query(core.Author.papers).group_by(core.Author.id).count().first()` = `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'first'`
- ...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/25118256/99594

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Found the solutions:

1. The number of authors each paper has: `db.s.query(core.Paper.title, func.count(core.Author.id)).join(core.Paper.authors).group_by(core.Paper.id).all()`
2. The number of papers each author has: `db.s.query(core.Author.name, func.count(core.Author.id)).join(core.Author.papers).group_by(core.Author.id).all()`

Relevant: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.having